# jQuery drag and drop sortable divs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to make image containers in the package [jFiler](http://filer.grandesign.md/) draggable, so that I can sort image positions after upload with drag and drop. Here is the [full script](https://jsfiddle.net/y1o8xrgd/3/), but the example is not working. I have added `id="sortable"` to parent div in jFiler template, and added this to my all.js:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
          containment: "parent",
          placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
      });
```

But it is not working for some reason. 
This is my jFiler.js:

```
$('#upload').filer({
            limit: null,
            maxSize: null,
            extensions: null,
            changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><h1>+</h1></div>',
            showThumbs: true,
            appendTo: '.uploaded_items',
            theme: "default",
            templates: {
                box: '<div class="jFiler-item-list" id="sortable"></div>',
                item: '<div class="jFiler-item img-container">\
                            {{fi-image}}\<div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></span></a>\
</div></div>',
                itemAppend: '<div class="jFiler-item img-container dragImg">\
                            {{fi-image}}\<div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></span></a>\
</div></div>',
                progressBar: '<div class="bar"></div>',
                itemAppendToEnd: false,
                removeConfirmation: false,
                _selectors: {
                    list: '.jFiler-item-list',
                    item: '.jFiler-item',
                    progressBar: '.bar',
                    remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action',
                }
            },
```

After upload, it creates html that looks like this:

```
<div class="uploaded_items">
   <div class="jFiler-items jFiler-row">
      <div class="jFiler-item-list" id="sortable">
         <div class="jFiler-item img-container" data-jfiler-index="3" style="">
            <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-image"><img src="http://myApp.app/imagecache/thumb/bear_PNG1190.png" draggable="false"></div>
            <div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></i></span></a></div>
         </div>
         <div class="jFiler-item img-container" data-jfiler-index="2" style="">
            <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-image"><img src="http://myApp.app/imagecache/thumb/bear_PNG1189.png" draggable="false"></div>
            <div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></i></span></a></div>
         </div>
         <div class="jFiler-item img-container" data-jfiler-index="1" style="">
            <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-image"><img src="http://myApp.app/imagecache/thumb/bear_PNG1188.png" draggable="false"></div>
            <div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></i></span></a></div>
         </div>
         <div class="jFiler-item img-container" data-jfiler-index="0" style="">
            <div class="jFiler-item-thumb-image"><img src="http://myApp.app/imagecache/thumb/bear_PNG1183.png" draggable="false"></div>
            <div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></i></span></a></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I call my scripts in following order:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/zurb/zurb.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-filer/jquery-filer.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/editor/editor.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/datepicker/datepicker.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.pjax/1.9.6/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/moment/moment.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/charts.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/all.js') }}"></script>
```

Updated code:

I have also used this:

```
$(".dragdiv").each(function(){
            makeElementAsDragAndDrop($(this));
        });

        $('.images-refresh').hide();
        $('.images-refresh').click(function(){
            $(this).closest("form").submit()
        });

        function makeElementAsDragAndDrop(elem) {
            $(elem).draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                cursor: "move",
                helper: "clone"
            });
            $(elem).droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $('.images-form a').hide();
                    $('.images-refresh').show();
                    var $dragElem = $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
                    $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);
                    makeElementAsDragAndDrop(this);
                    makeElementAsDragAndDrop($dragElem);

                }
            });
        }
```

And that works fine on elements that are not created with jFiler, like the ones that I have in the edit form:

```
      @foreach($images as $image)
        <div class="large-2 columns end dragdiv">
            <img src="http://coop.app/{{ $image->path}}">
        </div>
      @endforeach
```

But it is still not working with divs that are created by jFiler. They unlike the other divs that are not created by jFiler don't get `ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-droppable` attributes.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Are other jQuery UI elements working? Is all the proper jQuery libraries being loaded? Do you have a jsfiddle or other working example of the problem?

Comment: I don't get any errors in the console. I am not using any other jQuery UI elements, and athe libraries are seem to be loading. I don't have a working example yet, but I will make one.

Comment: Looking at your Script order, it's possible one of the other JS files is conflicting?

Comment: Everything else works fine, so I don't think so.

Comment: Images are uploaded, via Ajax? Or do the images within `#sortable` appear after the JS is loaded? If the latter, you need to update the sortable so it's aware of the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running [refresh()](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) once items are uploaded.

> Refresh the sortable items. Triggers the reloading of all sortable items, causing new items to be recognized.

I am not familiar with this plugin, so making a guess on the function to use:

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    containment: "parent",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
  });
  $('#upload').filer({
    limit: null,
    maxSize: null,
    extensions: null,
    changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><h1>+</h1></div>',
    showThumbs: true,
    appendTo: '.uploaded_items',
    theme: "default",
    templates: {
      box: '<div class="jFiler-item-list" id="sortable"></div>',
      item: '<div class="jFiler-item img-container">\
                            {{fi-image}}\<div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></span></a>\
</div></div>',
      itemAppend: '<div class="jFiler-item img-container dragImg">\
                            {{fi-image}}\<div class="overlay"><a href="#"><span><i class="jFiler-item-trash-action ion-trash-a"></span></a>\
</div></div>',
      progressBar: '<div class="bar"></div>',
      itemAppendToEnd: false,
      removeConfirmation: false,
      _selectors: {
        list: '.jFiler-item-list',
        item: '.jFiler-item',
        progressBar: '.bar',
        remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action',
      }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
      $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this but then I get:
jquery.js:253 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: This suggests the sortable is not being activated or run in your script. We will need to see more of the script.

Comment: Okay. When the page loads, the selector has 0 elements. So you need to call sortable after you have at least 1 item uploaded. Will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes, it worked when I have put it into the succes part of the upload, thank you!

Comment: hello @Marco I'm having the same problem with you. can you share how exactly you solved this? thanks.